# ThreeJS video texture demands CORS headers even when the <video> tag doesn't require it

Tags: html, video, three.js, cors, firebase-storage

I have a localhost web server running a page that plays a remote video (from Firestore Storage) in a `<video>` tag. The video plays correctly. Ok, great. Now I want to use that video as a texture in a ThreeJS canvas (using `THREE.VideoTexture`). But instead of showing the video, ThreeJS starts repeatedly printing

`THREE.WebGLState: DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The video element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.`

in an infinite loop.

Does my video really need CORS headers set ONLY inside a ThreeJS canvas? And if so, why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does my video really need CORS headers set ONLY inside a ThreeJS canvas?

Yes.

> And if so, why?

CORS is required when you want JavaScript to read data from another origin (as opposed to simply letting the browser render the data without your JavaScript touch it).

When you use it as a texture, you need to read the video data and process it with JavaScript.

> How do I fix this?

Configure the server you are pulling the video from to give you permission with CORS, or move the data so it is on the same origin.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, because the video was hosted on the server with a different domain. That server provided CORS, but additionally I should added a crossorigin="anonymous" to my video, like this

```
<video src="URL" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

Important to add it initially. When I tried to add it dynamically, after the video tag already exist, it didn't work.